# Using a custom timestamp in Laravel 5 returns an error

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, eloquent

So in my migrations I added a column as such:

`$table->timestamp('due_at');`

And then I allowed the user to set a due date for a task, but when I try to execute:

`$task->due_at->diffForHumans()`

I get this error

> Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string

My custom timestamp has exactly the same format as the `created_at` and `update_at`, yet it returns an error.

What can I do to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to also declare it in the model, otherwise Laravel won't know that it's a Carbon instance. For instance:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'due_at'];
```

And here's some documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Carbon::parse($task->due_at)->diffForHumans()
```